# Execute Python script located on remote Windows machine from Linux server

Tags: linux, ssh, python, windows, remote

I have following task:
I have Linux (RedHat) server and Windows machine. I need to execute Python script located on Windows side from Linux using ssh.
SSH server with password-less access is configured on Windows machine.
I tried following command:

```
$ ssh sshuser@windows_host_IP /drives/c/Users/sshuser/PythonScripts/myscript.py
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe: can't open file '/drives/c/Users/sshuser/PythonScripts/myscript.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Then i tried this:

```
$ ssh sshuser@windows_host_IP C:/Users/sshuser/PythonScripts/myscript.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sshuser/PythonScripts/myscript.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

This looks more like Python error, but script works normally on Windows side.

Could you please suuggest what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Using that way, you're currently running your script on Windows ... is it really the goal ?

If yes, then i guess that your SSH session is probably missing a correctly set `PYTHONPATH` because the error reported is that it just can find the `numpy` module.
I don't really know how python works under Windows but, in my opinion, it's probably because your `sshuser` don't have access to `numpy` module (maybe installed using another user ?).

If you want to execute the script under Linux after fetching it from the windows host, then you probably should run

`sshuser@windows_host_IP "type C:/Users/sshuser/PythonScripts/myscript.py" | python -`

This command will makes windows dump the script to stdout and pipe it to your local pyton interpreter

Comment: Yes, my goal is to run script on Windows machine.

Comment: So you have to dig regarding `PYTHONPATH`-like settings under windows or ask on another stackexchange cause Unix & Linux StackExchange  isn't the best place to solve windows issues ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your idea. There was issue with PYTHONPATH for correct user. It was configured but for another user. Now it is solved.